# How does one return a 'const' data.table from an R function?

Tags: r, data.table

> How does one return a `const data.table` from an `R` function?

A `data.table` from the `data.table` package is *passed to* and *returned from* functions by reference.

Hence, a function that returns a `data.table` allows the calling function to modify the returned `data.table`.

So the question is: *How does one return a const `data.table` from an `R` function?*

There are several obvious solutions that do not work for us:

- Call `copy()` on the `data.table` on return.

  ```
  constByCopy <- function() {
    dt <- ... # dt is a data.table not created in the current environment
    ...
    return(copy(dt)) 
  }
  ```

  This works; however, our `data.table`'s are large enough to cause this solution to not be viable.
- Use `lockBinding()` and `unlockBinding()`. This however, does not work with `data.table`, as one is still able to modify the locked `data.table`. (This is analogous to the difference between `int * const`and `int const * const` in C++.)

Comment: From your first point, it seems as if it is okay for the table to be modifiable.  If so, why don't you just return the `data.table` uncopied?  Once the function is done running (which is what happens at the return point), there should be no access to the `data.table` memory location other than the return value, so there is no need to copy it anyway since the original is no longer available.

Comment: I don't fully follow your post/question. You want to return a `data.table` that can not be modified by reference?

Comment: @KellyDavis `lockBinding` works fine for me. Could you post how you are using it?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, `ee = new.env(); ee$dt = data.table(x=1:5); lockBinding("dt", ee); ee$dt[, y := 6:10]; ee$dt` - my guess is that this should be caught.

Comment: @BrodieG It is not OK for the data.table to be modified. Also, what you say about the return value is true if the `data.table` was created in the function's environment. If it was not, as is true in our situation, then simply returning the `data.table` allows it to be modified.

Comment: @Arun Yes. I think that's a fair summary.

Comment: Kelly, you might want to update your example so that the `data.table` is not created in the function as you have it now.

Comment: You pass a data.table to a function that *could* be modified by reference (from within the function),  but you don't want it to be modified by reference after returning..? It doesn't make sense to me.. What's the rationale?

Comment: @Arun I think your example is a good illustration of the problem we are having. Your example in `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)` allows one to modify `dt` with out the standard `cannot change value of locked binding for 'dt'` showing up.

Comment: @BrodieG Good point. Will do

Comment: @Arun We have several large data sets we load from disk into `data.table`'s on program start. These large data sets should never be modified or copied by any code in the program, and they should only be loaded once. The various getXXX() functions which return these data sets are the "guardians" of the large data sets and should return const versions of the data sets.

Comment: @KellyDavis, assuming that `lockBinding` issue is fixed, an attempt to use `:=` would result in an error. Meaning, you're not prepared to use `:=` at all. So, why not just *not use* `:=` and any `set*` functions at all on your original data within your `getXXX` functions? My question is, *how will fixing `lockBinding` issue help your case*?

Comment: Again I think the analogy to C++ is apropos. What `lockBinding()` does is create something like `data.table * const` a constant pointer to a mutable data.table. What it "should" do is create a `data.table const * const` a constant pointer to a constant `data.table`

Comment: @Arun We have a large code base and many developers. Having the `lockBinding` issue fixed would ensure that any time any developer made a mistake and modified one of the `data.table`'s, our unit tests would catch it and the bug would not lead to some strange runtime error occurring on some line of code far from the bug.

Comment: I understand your problem (now). I'm just wondering if it's worth it (for your case). Because, you'd want to block the usage of `:=` and `set*` functions basically. Meaning `joins` and update by reference is out of the picture. That'd reduce the capabilities to `reshaping` and `aggregations`...

Comment: On another note, I remember discussing with Matt several months ago about working with shallow copies (and have an attribute similar to reference counting in future R-versions) so that we can still use the sub-assign by reference feature wherever possible. That'd be a great way to go about. It definitely would make things much more easier with R's reference counting, I believe. But there's no time frame on that yet.

Comment: I've added [issue #778](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/778).

Comment: NP. Just to clarify, [locked binding just sets bit 14 of the gp field](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d1ff5761558ee578054d458a3199ff3f8079ede6/src/main/envir.c#L78).