# R: How to make a data.table read-only without copying it (e. g. for data validation)

Tags: r, data.table, readonly

I do data wrangling (ETL) to load new data into a data base and want to let users implement their own data validation functions based on my existing `data.table` object that contains the prepared data.

How can I avoid that the user can change (modify) the data of my `data.table` within the validation function (intentionally or unintentionally) without making a copy (since it slows down the validation processing and therefore the whole ETL process)?

Locking/write-protecting the data is only required temporarily within the validation function...

Simplified example:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[, row.number := 1:(.N)]  # add a row number column to allow identification of invalid rows
DT[c(3,6,7), cyl := 100]    # create some data errors (100 cylinders in the car)

# correctly implemented validate function (does not change the data)
validate <- function(data) {
  data[cyl > 10, .(row.number = row.number, col.name = "cyl", col.value = cyl,
                   severity = "ERROR", msg = "More than 10 cylinders")]
}

validate(DT)
```

The output is OK and the `data.table` passed to the `validate()` function is not changed:

```
   row.number col.name col.value severity                    msg
1:          3      cyl       100    ERROR More than 10 cylinders
2:          6      cyl       100    ERROR More than 10 cylinders
3:          7      cyl       100    ERROR More than 10 cylinders
```

**What I want to avoid is that a user implements `validate()` like this and modifies the original data:**

```
validate.with.side.effects <- function(data) {
  data[, max.cyl := 10]  # this adds a new column into the original data.table!
  data[cyl > max.cyl, .(row.number = row.number, col.name = "cyl", col.value = cyl, severity = "ERROR", msg = "More than 10 cylinders")]
}
```

This implementation would modify the original data.table in `DT`!

**Update:**

There is an open feature request for that:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1086

The feature request is based on a similar requirement in a different context (immutable data in package): [Lock or protect a data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29085334/4468078)

**Update 2**

There is another similar feature request for that:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/778

And another similar SO question:
[How does one return a 'const' data.table from an R function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25426810/4468078)

**Update 3:** Could an immutable data.frame be used?

Generally yes (to make a `data.frame` read-only) but this solution does not meet the requirements of the question:

```
library(plyr)
idf <- idata.frame(DT)
idf[, max.cly := 10]
# Error in `:=`(max.cly, 10) :
#  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

validate(idf)
# Error in `[.idf`(data, cyl > 10, .(row.number = row.number, col.name = "cyl",  :
#                                     object 'cyl' not found

# it is no longer a data.table...
class(idata.frame(DT))
# [1] "idf"         "environment"

# so that the data.table syntax does NOT work anymore...
idf[cyl > 10, .(row.number = row.number, col.name = "cyl", col.value = cyl,
                severity = "ERROR", msg = "More than 10 cylinders")]
# Error in `[.idf`(idf, cyl > 10, .(row.number = row.number, col.name = "cyl",  :
#                                    object 'cyl' not found
```

Comment: I think you are not explaining the whole picture. What would a user do with a data.table that can't be changed? Are you trying to avoid using a proper database and providing the user with an API?

Comment: @Roland: I have tried to simplify the story since validation is just an example. My use case is: I provide an ETL framework that calls user-defined validation functions and I upload data only if the validation was successful. Therefore I do the transformation "in-memory" with R and then call the user-defined validation function so I want to prevent the user-defined validation function to change my already prepared data (that exists only in-memory in the current R session!).

Comment: You should be able to `setattr(idf, '.data.table.locked', TRUE)`, though I'm not sure this won't be unset by internal code.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for the code snippet, it seems to prevent `:=` updates but I couldn't find an official documentation for that at the official web site (except this pull request comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2918). If I assign a new value using the `data.frame` syntax (`dt[2, 1] = 100`) I can still update the `data.table` (even though not by ref ;-) Have you found an official documentation for this feature?

Comment: there is none  I would consider it internal behavior as we don't have any tests for using that as a way to get immutable DT. If you really want immutable DT it might be easier (and certainly better documented) to use dtplyr as of now

Answer (score 1):

Would an [immutable data frame](https://github.com/genome-vendor/r-cran-plyr/blob/master/R/immutable.r) allow you to accomplish what you need?

R's objects are usually immutable and employ copy-on-use semantics to apply functions (see [this link](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/03/using-closures-as-objects-in-r/) for more details). data.table is a bit of an odd duck since it allows direct interaction with the object, bypassing copy-on-use which makes it more like a mutable object. The scenario you have described requires an object with both mutable and immutable properties. You may have to copy dt in order to apply validation without modifying the original object.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Copying the `data.table` is not what I want due to performance reasons (large number of rows) and it must be a `data.table` (not a `data.frame`) to support the fast syntax and indexing in the validation logic. BTW: I would call it "copy on (first) write", not "copy on use" semantics...

Comment: The OP clearly states that you wish to avoid copying the data due to hits to performance. My answer respects that criteria, and merely points out that data.table was not designed for this sort of operation. Also, data.tables are in effect extensions of data.frames, and inherit the methods of the former when the latter are unavailable. The plyr immutable data.frame creates a new object (B) with pointers to the original data (A) and adds additional variables, all without modifying or copying A. You can then run validation on B and return A, if successful. This should accomplish your objective.

Comment: I want to use `data.table` syntax for performance reasons (as described in the question) and would guess that wrapping the original data.table using plyr would not guarantee immutability if I use `data.table` syntax (mainly in-place updates with `:=`). I will test this and post a feed back here. Anyhow thanks for show an possible alternative (+1)

Comment: I have tested `plyr::idata.frame`, please see my results in the updated question (section "update 3"). If you want you could copy this into your answer to document this alternative solution (works for `data.frame`s only)