# Prevent change to dataframe format in R

Tags: r, data.table, format

I have a dataframe that must have a specific layout. Is there a way for me to make R reject any command I attempt that would change the number or names of the columns?

It is easy to check the format of the data table manually, but I have found no way to make R do it for me automatically every time I execute a piece of code.

regards

Comment: It's a bit of a strange request. Why would you be running code that might change the name / number of your columns without your permission? The sanest thing to do would be to make a copy of your data frame. For example, if your data frame is called `df` then simply do `df_backup <- df`. If somehow you screw up the data frame then restore the original `df` with `df <- df_backup`. There are alternative approaches that I can think of, but this is really the simplest.

Comment: Two half-baked ideas that come to mind are (1) keeping your data in a remote database with locked columns and manipulating using DBI, dbplyr, etc; or (2) using an R6 object with methods that only permit allowable changes to the data. NB, I lack the knowledge of either database management or R6 to know if either of these is really feasible.

Comment: Using data.table, maybe try: `setattr(DT, '.data.table.locked', TRUE)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44995065/680068

Comment: For @AllanCameron's comment about creating `df_backup`, note that if your object is of class `data.table`, then you'll need to explicitly `copy(df)`. As an example of why, try: `A <- data.table(a=1:2); B <- A; A[,b:=3:4]`, and note that `B` has column `b`; this modified Allan's comment to be `df_backup <- copy(df)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dabbler, I edited the tags to change from [tag:datatable] (an ambiguous label) to [tag:data.table] because of your mention of "format of the data table manually", but I realize that you may be using "data table" to mean a frame you have in R. Please clarify if the class of the object you're using is `"data.frame"`, `"data.table"`, `"tbl_df"`, or something else. Also, I think the comments posed by AllanCameron and zephryl are relevant and likely good places for you to move forward from, but StackOverflow is not really geared to be a "conversation forum", are there better details you can share?

Comment: I wonder if it could be helpful to define n new R class for this type of object.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t offer the level of foolproof safety I think you’re looking for (hard to know without more details), but you could define a [function operator](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-operators.html) that yields modified functions that error if changes to columns are detected:

```r
same_cols <- function(fn) {
  function(.data, ...) {
    out <- fn(.data, ...)
    stopifnot(identical(sort(names(.data)), sort(names(out))))
    out
  }
}
```

For example, you could create modified versions of dplyr functions:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_mutate <- same_cols(mutate)
my_summarize <- same_cols(summarize)
```

which work as usual if columns are preserved:

```r
mtcars %>%
  my_mutate(mpg = mpg / 2) %>%
  head()
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         10.50   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     10.50   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        11.40   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    10.70   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout  9.35   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant            9.05   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mtcars %>% 
  my_summarize(across(everything(), mean))
#        mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am
# 1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625
#     gear   carb
# 1 3.6875 2.8125
```

But throw errors if changes to columns are made:

```r
mtcars %>%
  my_mutate(mpg2 = mpg / 2)
# Error in my_mutate(., mpg2 = mpg/2) : 
#   identical(sort(names(.data)), sort(names(out))) is not TRUE

mtcars %>%
  my_summarize(mpg = mean(mpg))
# Error in my_summarize(., mpg = mean(mpg)) : 
#   identical(sort(names(.data)), sort(names(out))) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention the names and columns need to be the same, also realize that with data.table also names are updated by reference. See the example below.

```
foo <- data.table(
  x = letters[1:5],
  y = LETTERS[1:5]
)

colnames <- names(foo)

colnames
# [1] "x" "y"

setnames(foo, colnames, c("a", "b"))
foo[, z := "oops"]

colnames
# [1] "a" "b" "z"

identical(colnames, names(foo))
# [1] TRUE
```

To check that **both** the columns and names are unalterated (and in same order here) you can take right away a copy of the names. And after each code run, you can check the current names with the copied names.

```
foo <- data.table(
  x = letters[1:5],
  y = LETTERS[1:5]
)

colnames <- copy(names(foo))

setnames(foo, colnames, c("a", "b"))
foo[, z := "oops"]

identical(colnames, names(foo))
[1] FALSE

colnames
# [1] "x" "y"

names(foo)
# [1] "a" "b" "z"
```